# I have the list of contacts appear in my android App. How is it possible that upon clicking on the name, it saves the number into a String?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-contacts

I have the following code to have the list of contacts appear on my screen:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        return super.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    ListView lv;
    Cursor cursor1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null , null , null , null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);

        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to );
        setListAdapter(listadapter);

        lv = getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would like to enable the user, that he can save the number in a String with clicking on a name. How should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement `setOnItemClickListener` on your listview then using cursor and moveToPosition method passing position as parametar to get the position  then again using the cursor get the number from name something like this:

`lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        cursor1.moveToPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});`

*Note* I didn't test the code so I don't know am I right.